# POSIX Timer Signal not being blocked in signal handler

Tags: c++, c, posix, signals

I am setting up a POSIX timer to call a function at a given rate. I setup a signal handler and initialize the timer, etc...everything works. However, according to all of the documentation I've read I should never receive a signal from the timer while I'm in the signal handler (it should automatically be blocked). To take this one step further, I even set the sa_mask of the sigaction to block all signals...I still get multiple calls to the signal handler...

Setting up the handler:

```
    // establish the signal handler
    sigset_t blockMask;
    struct sigaction sigact;

    sigfillset(&blockMask);
    //sigemptyset(&blockMask);
    sigact.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigact.sa_sigaction = callbackIn;
    sigact.sa_mask = blockMask;
    if( sigaction(ElmoSynchronizer::NEXT_RT_SIGNAL_NUMBER, &sigact, NULL) == -1 )
    {
        return CanStatus( CanStatus::SYSTEM_ERROR, __FUNCTION__, "Couldn't establish signal handler for timer" );   
    }

    // create the timer
    struct sigevent sev;
    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_signo = ElmoSynchronizer::NEXT_RT_SIGNAL_NUMBER;
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = this;
    if( timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, timerIn) == -1 )
    {
        return CanStatus( CanStatus::SYSTEM_ERROR, __FUNCTION__, "Couldn't create POSIX timer for timer" );
    }

    // start the timer
    struct itimerspec timerSpec;
    timerSpec.it_value = firstExecTime;
    timerSpec.it_interval = ElmoSynchronizer::getTimespecFromDouble(1.0/rate_hz);
    if( timer_settime(*timerIn, TIMER_ABSTIME, &timerSpec, NULL) == -1 )
    {
        return CanStatus( CanStatus::SYSTEM_ERROR, __FUNCTION__, "Couldn't start timer for timer" );
    }
```

The callback (yes, i know printfs are bad in signal handlers):

```
 void ElmoSynchronizer::rootPvtCallback(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{

    // get a pointer to the ElmoSynchronizer calling this
    ElmoSynchronizer *elmoSync = (ElmoSynchronizer*)si->si_value.sival_ptr;

    struct timespec startTime;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &startTime);
    uint32_t expectedTime_us = elmoSync->getMasterClockTimeFromTimespec_us(elmoSync->m_pvtSupplyStartTime) + ((elmoSync->m_updateIteration * elmoSync->m_elmoUpdatePeriod_ms) * 1000);
    uint32_t actualTime_us = elmoSync->getMasterClockTimeFromTimespec_us(startTime);
    uint32_t currIter = elmoSync->m_updateIteration+1;

    printf("---> PVT update - iteration %u @ %u\n", currIter, elmoSync->getMasterClockTimeFromTimespec_us(startTime));
    fflush(stdout);

    // iterate through all of our callbacks and call them!
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < elmoSync->m_elmos.size(); i++ )
    {
        // get the position/velocity pair
        posVelPair_t pv = elmoSync->m_elmos[i].callback(elmoSync->m_elmos[i].elmo);

        // now add the point to the elmo
        elmoSync->m_elmos[i].elmo->addPvtPoints( pv.position_cnts, pv.velocity_cps, elmoSync->m_elmoUpdatePeriod_ms );

    }
    elmoSync->m_updateIteration++;

    if( elmoSync->m_updateIteration == 250 )
    {
        usleep(elmoSync->m_elmoUpdatePeriod_ms*4000);
    }

    // make sure we executed fast enough   
    struct timespec endTime;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &endTime);
    double totalCallbackTime_s = getSecondsFromTimespec(ElmoSynchronizer::ts_subtract(endTime, startTime));
    if( totalCallbackTime_s > (elmoSync->m_elmoUpdatePeriod_ms * 1.0E-3) )
    {
        //ROS_WARN("PVT update - Callback execution took longer than update period! %lfs actual / %lfs period", totalCallbackTime_s, (elmoSync->m_elmoUpdatePeriod_ms * 1.0E-3));
        //overflowedRootPvtCallbackPeriod = true;
    }

    printf("<--- PVT update - iteration %u @ %u\n", currIter, elmoSync->getMasterClockTimeFromTimespec_us(endTime));
    fflush(stdout);

    /*
    printf("PVT update - iteration: %u actual: %u expected: %u diff: %u cbTime: %u\n",
        elmoSync->m_updateIteration, actualTime_us, expectedTime_us, actualTime_us-expectedTime_us, (uint32_t)(totalCallbackTime_s * 1.0E6));
    fflush(stdout);
    */
}
```

Output:

```
---> PVT update - iteration 248 @ 13315103
<--- PVT update - iteration 248 @ 13315219
---> PVT update - iteration 249 @ 13346107
<--- PVT update - iteration 249 @ 13346199
---> PVT update - iteration 250 @ 13377104    // two entrances
---> PVT update - iteration 251 @ 13408109    // second entrance
<--- PVT update - iteration 251 @ 13408197
---> PVT update - iteration 252 @ 13439109
<--- PVT update - iteration 252 @ 13439254
---> PVT update - iteration 253 @ 13470120
<--- PVT update - iteration 253 @ 13470216
---> PVT update - iteration 254 @ 13501122
<--- PVT update - iteration 254 @ 13501213
<--- PVT update - iteration 250 @ 13501317    // exit for iteration 250
---> PVT update - iteration 255 @ 13532078
<--- PVT update - iteration 255 @ 13532170
---> PVT update - iteration 256 @ 13563109
<--- PVT update - iteration 256 @ 13563242
```

Comment: Nevermind `printf`; `usleep` **isn't** async-signal-safe.  See [IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 Signal Concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html): "when a signal interrupts an unsafe function and the signal-catching function calls an unsafe function, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: And likely all the other code in there messes with a ElmoSynchronizer which by the looks of it is far from async safe, this sounds like a race condition bomb waiting to go off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting a periodic timer, shoot it again when the signal handler ends.

When you create the timer do this

```
// start the timer
//struct itimerspec timerSpec;
this->timerSpec_.it_value = firstExecTime;
this->timerSpec_.it_interval = 0; //one-shot 
if( timer_settime(*timerIn, TIMER_ABSTIME, &this->timerSpec_, NULL) == -1 )
{
    return CanStatus( CanStatus::SYSTEM_ERROR, __FUNCTION__, "Couldn't start timer for timer" );
}

// from now we will shoot the timer with this value
this->timerSpec_.it_value = ElmoSynchronizer::getTimespecFromDouble(1.0/rate_hz);

// store *timerIn in also in ElmoSynchronizer
this->timerId_ = *timerIn;
```

Then append to the very end of the `ElmoSynchronizer::rootPvtCallback` function this

```
//shoot our the timer again
if( timer_settime(elmoSync->timerId_, 0, &elmoSync->timerSpec_, NULL) == -1 )
{
    return CanStatus( CanStatus::SYSTEM_ERROR, __FUNCTION__, "Couldn't restart timer" );
}
```

By the way, I would make the whole thing with threads and semaphores, so the synchronizer could simply check whether the PVT updating process ended or not in a defined duration.
POSIX offers them and is not harder to implement than a timer.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to debug signal handlers I make an array to put the debug info into (instead of using printf).  Collect up data for a number of signal handler calls, then dump out the contents of the array to see what happened.

You might see a different order to the output.